# Where to run the put command

Tags: snowflake-schema

I am a windows users with a scala kernel set up on Jupyter Notebook. I have a ML model saved as .pmml file saved in a jar file and that jar file I need to put in the snowflake stage. However in the snowflake documentation the following command is used to do that

The command for windows is :
put file://c:\data\data.csv @~/staged;

My question is where should I execute the command with my user directory details,should it be in the scala kernel in Jupyter notebook, in cmd or in the snowflake itself?

My analogous command:
put file:C:\Users\psengar\myJar.jar @~/staged

Comment: PUT command can be run SnowSQL and the directory to point to JAR location which  need to be stored.

Comment: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009XCitqSAD/how-to-execute-put-file-command-to-load-data-to-snowflake-table-from-pyhon-jupyter-nb 
Relevant link for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run the put command on [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.